# Wordpress is not working on ubuntu 18.04, http://xxxxxxxxxx/wp-admin/install.php is giving no object found 404 error

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, installation

I am setting up a development environment for wordpress, Mysql and apache are fine, xampp is working fine, i am able to to make and run laravel projects using xampp/lampp. 
I have followed this tutorial -> https://youtu.be/sUTGFFp5V4U?list=LLmjZCB5OkQ0jG7aVejm2OwA everything works as described in tutorial but im stuck at 6:40 in the video

**"ip"/wp-admin/install.php** doesnt open up it say

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

192.168.10.10
Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2q PHP/7.2.13 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall ubuntu and followed the series of the tutorial by https://www.digitalocean.com/ and everything work fine for me... It's not a proper answer, However, grinding on the web for few days, That was my way out.